# Swift Core data can't store data second time : Cocoa error 1560

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, core-data

I have core data and three object inside them. Let say I have objects: `Parent, Child, Item`.

`Parent` have `Set<Child>`, `Child` have `Set<Item>`, so with other words,

```
Parent have one to many relationship with Child
Child have one to many relationship with Item

Parent: 
  - var childs : Set<Child>

Child:
  - var items : Set<Item>
```

For storing data inside I have method :

```
func insert(parent : Parent)  {

    // remove all old Childs
    parent.removeChild(Parent.childs)

    for data in datas {

        let child = self.newChildFromData(data)

        for data2 in datas2 {

            let item = self.newItemFromData2(data2)

            child.addItem(item)
        }

        parent.addChild(child)
    }

    do {
       try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print(error.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** This is not real code, but it is close enough to understand the problem.

When I run method for the first time (empty database), it work normal, but when I run it for the second time, it give me error

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1560.)

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorKey=server, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject...
```

What that could be?

Comment: 1560 means there are multiple errors; 1570 is the value for "NSValidationMissingMandatoryPropertyError" which presumably means you have a property with a validation constraint which makes it mandatory, but your code sets it to nil.

Comment: Yes I read about that, but why then when I first run method it store elements without error, but with second time, with same objects this error occurred? I suspect that there is something wrong with removing old values, but I don't know what.

Comment: Do you have a constraint that every child must have a parent?  parent.removeChild(parent.childs) will mean the Child objects no longer have a parent (it doesn't actually delete the Child objects).

Comment: Yes, now i figure it out, that this was true. I have mandatory parent field. When I remove relationship this was invalid entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting errors after changing your code to suit the two requirements try cleaning your build and delete the application from your iPhone Simulator/iPhone device. You can also refer the library [Core Data Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/Reference/reference.html)

In addition you can also refer [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmCustomizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH8-SW1). It will help you in migrating your core data model.

Comment: Yes, if I delete my application and run it again it work, but when I run the code for reload my data it present error again. This is not model versioning or transitioning error. I need to reload data on demand.